# Detect if image is a perceptual exact duplicate

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hash, computer-vision

**[Problem]**

For an application, I am looking to compare images with an original. With the comparison, I want to determine if they are an exact perceptual match. They could have different resolution e.g. thumbnail or different compression levels. As long as the images look similar, it would be a match. But if the image is altered e.g. cropping, aspect ratio change, perceptual image updates e.g. a highlight or mark, it would not be considered a match.

**[Already tried]**

1. phash - from imagehash https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/
   This seems to work well for detecting the different versions but has too many false positives and is too lenient.
2. Phash from imagededup https://github.com/idealo/imagededup
   This detects the copies similar to above but this also has a lot of false positives especially ignores minor edits
3. cv2 template matching https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/template-matching-using-opencv-in-python/
   This is the best so far in detecting edits but this fails on compressed images and hence has too many false negatives

**[Need Advice]**

1. Any other options you would suggest? Any other options in open cv, or any other models?
2. Is there a way to increase the sensitivity of phash?
3. Any ideas on how to accomplish this with a combination of methods?

It would be okay to trade performance a bit for accuracy for this use-case.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried any similarity match algorithm? like cosine etc?

Comment: @Jeril I am not aware of this for images, would you please shed some light on the approach?

Comment: You would need to extract embeddings from the images, which are n-dimensional vectors that can be measured for similarity using a distance metric such as the euclidean or cosine distance. You could also measure similarity between hash strings, using the Levenshtein or hamming distance, for example.

Comment: the word "exact" should not be used here. you will always deal with similarity/dissimilarity measures. -- so you consider *cropping* to cause relevant differences but *rescaling* is okay?

Comment: Try perceptual hash

Comment: @stateMachine Thank you for your suggestion, I am very much a beginner in this space. Would you have any suggestions on where to look for examples for this?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, you're right exact is a bit ambiguous here but you're correct the edits and cropping are bad but rescaling is okay as long as the image is perceptually the same. So here, exact is for being "perceptually exact"

Comment: @fmw42 I did try perceptual hash per my post, unfortunately it is too lenient on edits. I am looking to see if it could be a bit strict.

Comment: can you check [here](https://huggingface.co/blog/image-similarity) and [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/aliabdin1/find-similar-images-with-cosine-similarity)

Comment: You did not say which phash method(s) that you tried. There are a number of different methods. Some are better than others.

Comment: do you already know which two images to compare, or do you need to _find_ the image in a database?

Comment: @fmw42 sorry I am not aware there are different methods. I am just using imagehash.phash I'll update the question with the exact method.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, I already know which two images to compare.

Comment: then resample one or both so the sizes match, then take per pixel absolute/squared differences, then count the number of differences that go above some threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I have used phash value for checking image similarity in the past and it worked well for me. But it seems like you're looking for high accuracy so I'd suggest you to consider combining multiple methods to improve results. For instance, use template matching or feature-based matching to quickly identify close to exact matches, and then apply perceptual hashing to catch more subtle changes. Also keep in mind that you will have to tune parameters to get optimal results. So a little trial and error is required.

Since you had mentioned threshold with phashing, you might want to try the following approach if you have not yet:

```
from PIL import Image
import imagehash

# Load images
image1 = Image.open('1.jpg')
image2 = Image.open('2.jpg')

# Calculate perceptual hashes
hash1 = imagehash.phash(image1)
hash2 = imagehash.phash(image2)

# Define a threshold value
threshold = 10

# Calculate the Hamming distance between the hashes
hamming_distance = hash1 - hash2

# Compare the Hamming distance with the threshold
if hamming_distance <= threshold:
    print("Perceptually similar.")
else:
    print("Not perceptually similar.")
```

I have also worked on template matching for such a scenario. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load images
image1 = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
image2 = cv2.imread('2.jpg')

# Convert images to grayscale for template matching
gray_image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Use the entire image as the template
template = gray_image2

# Perform template matching
result = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_image1, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

# Define a similarity threshold for template matching
template_matching_threshold = 0.95

# Find positions where template matches above the threshold
locations = np.where(result >= template_matching_threshold)

if len(locations[0]) > 0:
    print("Similar")
else:
    print("Not similar")
```

The high threshold ensures checking for perceptually exact duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, this is my current approach. Would you have any example for template matching or feature based matching? 
Thank you!

Comment: I have just edited my answer to incorporate template matching. Hope it helps!